# print sizes of all folder and files in each drive using powershell

Tags: powershell

i am running below powershell command i am getting error:Trying to calculate the sizes of folder and files in each drive if size is lessthan 1KB then print size in KB otherwise in MB or GB

```
ls -Force | Add-Member -Force -Passthru -Type ScriptProperty -Name Length -Value {ls $this -Recurse -Force | Measure -Sum Length | Select -Expand Sum } | Sort-Object Length -Descending | Format-Table @{label="TotalSize (MB)";If ($_.Length -lt 1KB)  {expression={[Math]::Truncate($_.Length / 1KB)};width=14}  else {expression={[Math]::Truncate($_.Length / 1GB)};width=14}}, @{label="Mode";expression={$_.Mode};width=8}, Name
```

Error

```
    Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
    At line:1 char:230
    + ls -Force | Add-Member -Force -Passthru -Type ScriptProperty -Name 
    Length -Value {ls $this -Recurse -Force | Measure
    Sum Length | Select -Expand Sum } | Sort-Object Length -Descending |        
    Format-Table @{label="TotalSize (MB)";If ( <<<< $
     _.Length -lt 1KB) {expression={[Math]::Truncate($_.Length / 
    1KB)};width=14} else {expression={[Math]::Truncate($_.Lengt
    h / 1GB)};width=14}}, @{label="Mode";expression={$_.Mode};width=8}, 
    Name
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
    ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

Comment: Move the `if/else` inside the `expression={}` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message hints at, you can't just place any value expression directly inside a hashtable literal.

Move the condition inside the `Expression` scriptblock:

```
@{
    label="TotalSize (MB)"
    expression={
        if($_.Length -lt 1KB){
            [Math]::Truncate($_.Length / 1KB)
        }
        else{
            [Math]::Truncate($_.Length / 1GB)
        }
    }
    width=14
}
```

Although I think you should remove the `(MB)` part of the label in that case, since you're not actually showing the size in MB.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a helper function.

```
Function Get-FormattedBytes([decimal]$Bytes,[ValidateRange(0,15)]$Decimals=2){
    if ($Bytes -gt 1024PB){ return "$([Math]::Round(($Bytes/1024PB),$Decimals))EB" }
    $SufTable=@('B','KB','MB','GB','TB','PB',"EB")
    $Base = [Math]::Log($Bytes,1024);$Floor = [Math]::Floor($Base)
    $Value=[Math]::Pow(1024,$Base-$Floor);$Suffix=$SufTable[$Floor]
    return "$([Math]::Round($Value,$Decimals))$($Suffix)"
} #handles up to 687 Billion Exabytes of data, should be enough...
```

I put this together off an answer for a different language but can't remember where it is to provide credit.

Comment: That last comment :-P "640KB should suffice..."